# Function template with variable argument function as template argument

Tags: c++

Is is possible to have a generic function as a template argument, something along the lines of:

```cpp
template <typename RETURN, typename... ARGS, RETURN (fn)(ARGS...)> void method()
```

(not possible because the parameter pack is not the last argument)

I can have it as a function argument, but I need to able to actually generate separate instances at compile-time for each passed function so that I can use it as an argument in another template:

```cpp
template <typename RETURN, typename... ARGS> void method(RETURN (fn)(ARGS...)) {
  // wont be able to do this, fn is not a function with external linkage
  auto r = SomeTemplate<fn>();
}
```

Ideally, using only C++17, but every tip is welcome.

Comment: `template <auto Method> void method();`?

Comment: Do you need to retain `RETURN` and `ARGS...`? If not, Jarod's example should be sufficient, right?

Comment: I do need them, but I wonder if there isn't a way to get them from `auto Method`

Comment: You can extract them from auto indeed, either with a traits, or using helper function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can deduce the return and argument types from an `auto Method` template argument:

```
#include <tuple>
#include <iostream>

template <typename T> struct method_trait;
template <typename Ret,typename ...Args> struct method_trait<Ret(*)(Args...)> {
    using return_type = Ret;
    using arg_tuple = std::tuple<Args...>;
};

template <auto F>
auto foo() {
    typename method_trait<decltype(F)>::return_type res = std::apply(F,typename method_trait<decltype(F)>::arg_tuple{});
    return res;
}

int bar(int x,double y) {
    return x + y + 42;
}


int main() {
    std::cout << foo<bar>();
}
```

[Live Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/K55Eq4aM1)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `template <typename CALLABLE> void method() {}`.

The return type is available as `std::invoke_result_t<CALLABLE>`.

Using `std::is_invokable_v<CALLABLE, Args...>` you can *check* if `CALLABLE` can be called with the argument list `Args`.

There is no way std library to get the actual argument pack to my knowledge. However, there are attempts in "that general vincinity" that may be adapted to your requirements, depending on what you want the argument pack for.

E.g.,

"A type trait for signatures", https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2013/n3579.html

"Deducing function signatures", https://breese.github.io/2022/03/06/deducing-function-signatures.html (deducing a function type from any callable)

Answer (score 1):

You can use a partial specialization to deconstruct a full function type to its return type and arguments:

```cpp
template <typename Function>
struct SomeTemplate { };

template <typename Function>
struct Method;

template <typename Return, typename... Args>
struct Method<Return(Args...)> {
    using MethodType = Return(Args...);

    auto logic() -> void {
        auto r = SomeTemplate<MethodType>();
        // your logic goes here
    }

    template <typename Function>
    explicit Method(Function* mt) { }
};

template <typename Function>
Method(Function*) -> Method<Function>;

auto foo(int n) -> bool { return true; }

auto main() -> int {
    auto m = Method(foo);

    m.logic();
}
```

Comment: Doesn't this `template <typename Function>
Method(Function*) -> Method<Function>;` have the same problem? It compiles an instance per `Function` type, not for each individual function pointer. Which means that it cannot be used to instantiate.

Answer (score 1):

I would use [`std::integral_constant`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/integral_constant) to have a version where template argument are deducible, and then a `template<auto fn>` version:

```
#include <type_traits>

template <typename RETURN, typename... ARGS, RETURN (*fn)(ARGS...)>
void method(std::integral_constant<RETURN (*)(ARGS...), fn>)
{
  // ...
}

template <auto* fn>
void method()
{
    return method(std::integral_constant<decltype(fn), fn>{});
}
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/MK5jrc54E).

That helper function might be template lambda in C++20:

```
template <auto* fn>
void method()
{
    return []<typename RETURN, typename... ARGS>
        (std::integral_constant<RETURN (*)(ARGS...), fn>)
        {
            /*..*/
        }(std::integral_constant<decltype(fn), fn>{});
}
```

Comment: gcc builds this with `-std=c++17` but `clang` correctly refuses it. Still it is a very good solution, thanks.

Comment: Just added a demo, and the C++17 code works for clang/gcc...